# How to calculate Broadcast IP in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, math, ip, broadcast, subnet

I read that you have to add the binary IP and the reversed binary mask IP. But that leads to wrong results for me.

Thats how it looks now:
https://i.imgur.com/H3OiJd7.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 'wifi_ip' package? (https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_ip). It works for both Android and iOS, and it is as simple as:

```
WifiInfo info;
try {
  info = await GetWifiInfo.getWifiInfo;
} on PlatformException {
  print('Failed to get broadcast IP.');
}
```

Comment: oh thanks. but i dont want to get the current broadcast. i have 2 textfields. one with ip and one  with mask. i want to calculate the broadcast from the given parameters